# Unable to fetch all SQS messages by Lambda(Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Unable to fetch all SQS messages by Lambda(Python).
Its reading the Queue partially

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
response = sqs_client.receive_message(QueueUrl="queurlXXX.fifo",
MaxNumberOfMessages=10,WaitTimeSeconds=20,VisibilityTimeout=0)
for message in response.get("Messages", []):
    message_body = message["Body"]
    #print(message_body)
    ip_json=json.loads(message_body)
    op_json=json.dumps(ip_json)
    #print(op_json)
    if op_json:
        conn = pymssql.connect(host='DB Credentials', database='DbNAme', port='1433')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [table]([MessageId],[Document],[IsProcessed],[CreatedUtc],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedUtc],[ModifiedBy]) VALUES('messageid', %s,1,GETUTCDATE(),'system',GETUTCDATE(),'system');",(op_json))
        conn.commit()
    #print(f"Message body: {json.loads(message_body)}")
    #print(f"Receipt Handle: {message['ReceiptHandle']}")
return "Queue loaded"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reading the Queue partially"?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are saying that your `receive_message()` call did not return all messages in the Amazon SQS queue. This is a normal behaviour of Amazon SQS due to its highly distributed architecture.

From [Amazon SQS short and long polling - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html):

> **Consuming messages using short polling**
> When you consume messages from a queue using short polling, Amazon SQS samples a subset of its servers (based on a weighted random distribution) and returns messages from only those servers. **Thus, a particular `ReceiveMessage` request might not return all of your messages.** However, if you have fewer than 1,000 messages in your queue, a subsequent request will return your messages. If you keep consuming from your queues, Amazon SQS samples all of its servers, and you receive all of your messages.
>
> The following diagram shows the short-polling behavior of messages returned from a standard queue after one of your system components makes a receive request. Amazon SQS samples several of its servers (in gray) and returns messages A, C, D, and B from these servers. **Message E isn't returned for this request**, but is returned for a subsequent request.
>
> [image: Amazon SQS polling]